# List of any object T

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to avoid casting of any type. I have the following simple Bus class that you can use to register your handlers:

```
public interface IDomainEvent {}

public class Bus
{
    private static readonly IList<IHandler<IDomainEvent>> Handlers = new List<IHandler<IDomainEvent>>();

    public static void Register(IHandler<IDomainEvent> handler)
    {
        if (handler != null)
            Handlers.Add(handler);
    }

    public static void Raise<T>(T eventData) where T : IDomainEvent
    {
        foreach (var handler in Handlers)
        {
            handler.Handle(eventData);
        }
    }
}

public interface IHandler<T> 
{
    T Handle(T eventData);
}

public class UpdatePersonHandler : IHandler<Person>
{
    public Person Handle(Person eventData)
    {
        var test = eventData.Name;
        return eventData;
    }
}
```

This gives an error because it's not of type IDomainEvent

```
Bus.Register(new UpdatePersonHandler());
```

How can I restructure the Bus so that it is generic enough to hold ANY type of IHandler?

Obviously making `Bus<T>` is not the right solution, since Bus should handle any type of IHander

I've tried this (still error):

```
public interface IHandler<T> where T : IDomainEvent
{
    T Handle(T eventData);
}

public class UpdatePersonHandler : IHandler<Person> 
{
    public Person Handle(Person eventData)
    {
        var test = eventData.Name;
        return eventData;
    }
}

public class Person : IDomainEvent
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

> Argument 1: cannot convert from
>   'ConsoleApplication1.UpdatePersonHandler' to
>   'ConsoleApplication1.IHandler'

---

```
public class Bus<T>
{
    private static readonly IList<IHandler<T>> Handlers = new List<IHandler<T>>();

    public static void Register(IHandler<T> handler)
    {
        if (handler != null)
            Handlers.Add(handler);
    }

    public static void Raise(T eventData)
    {
        foreach (var handler in Handlers) {
            handler.Handle(eventData);
        }
    }
}
```

After this edit, code compiles and I'm able to run the following:

```
    Bus<Person>.Register(new UpdatePersonHandler());
    Bus<Person>.Raise(new Person {Name = "John"});
```

However, what about concurrency?, what if I want to handle `Bus<Animal>` ? at the same time. old values in `Bus.List<T>` would be lost-correct?

Comment: As `IDomainEvent` is currently empty, the obvious is just to make `UpdatePersonHandler` derive from that. What's stopping you doing this? (As an aside, empty interfaces are generally a code smell).

Comment: How is T represented on your bus?  Is it an XML serialization of the original object?  Is it an actual object?

Comment: it is actual object. it could be "Person" class or "Animal" class etc

Comment: Do you know the type T at compile time?

Comment: Yes. I do know T at compile time

Comment: OK.  Well, I'm with @PhilipKendall then.  I don't understand why you need the `IDomainEvent` interface to do this, especially if it won't have an implementation.  The only purpose it serves at the moment is to insure a compile error.

Comment: Fine. I can remove the interface, BUT that does not help me still since Bus would have to have Bus<T> specified, and that's not what I want. I want the Bus to be as broad as possible and accept any type of handlers. When I Specify Ilist<Handler<T>> => this is the issue

Comment: It looks like your code currently calls every event handler in the IList, regardless of type.  Is it your intention to eventually register *a single handler* for each type?

Comment: The code doesn't compile because you can't "Register" event handler T. and that's what I need to do. in order to do that I would have to make Bus<T> which I don't want to. Bus should handle ANY type

Comment: Intuitively, this feels over-engineered.  Instead of

    `private static readonly IList<IHandler<IDomainEvent>> Handlers`,

why not do something like `private static readonly Dictionary<Type, IHandler<T>> Handlers`?  You can then

    `public static void Raise<T>(T eventData)
    {
        Handlers[typeof(T)].Handle(eventData);
    }`

Comment: Please see Edit

Comment: It *still* looks like your code currently calls every event handler in the IList, regardless of type. Is it your intention to eventually register a single handler for each type?

Comment: That's not what I'm having issues with. What I'm after is to have a single static class Bus, with a list that handles ANY types of handlers<T>. When I do this:  Bus<Person>.Register(new UpdatePersonHandler()); and then Bus<Animal>.Register(new UpdateAnimalHandler()) wouldn't my list reset? and loose Person stuff?

Comment: Will `T` always be the same for every registered handler?

Comment: NO, that's what I'm getting at. list should hold any Hanlder of type T (T being different)

Comment: Will you have multiple handlers for each type `T`?  Or just one?

Comment: Yes. Multiple handlers for each type

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44131/discussion-between-robert-harvey-and-shane-km).

Answer (score 1):

Considering the limitations of C#'s type system wrt. generic constraints, and other things such as contra vs covariance vs invariance, etc (intersecting also with the CLR's own type system design choice), I believe it is going to be difficult for you to achieve that, *without* having to do any down casting *anywhere*. However, you may be able to at least hide most of it from the application/client tier (that is, the consumer of your statically type checked bus API) by using dependent generic constraints; e.g., something along the lines of:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

/// <summary>
/// SE 328643:
/// List of any object T
/// http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/328643/list-of-any-object-t
/// </summary>
public interface IDomainEvent { }

public interface IHandler<T> where T : IDomainEvent
{
    T Handle(T eventData);
}

public class Bus<T> where T : IDomainEvent
{
    private static IList<IHandler<T>> handlers = new List<IHandler<T>>();

    public static void Register<H>(H handler) where H : IHandler<T>
    {
        handlers.Add(handler);
    }

    public static void Raise(T eventData)
    {
        foreach (var handler in handlers)
        {
            handler.Handle(eventData);
        }
    }
}

public delegate void BusDispatch<T>(T eventData) where T : IDomainEvent;

public class AnyBus
{
    private static IDictionary<Type, Delegate> busDispatch =
        new Dictionary<Type, Delegate>
        {
            { typeof(Bus<Person>), (BusDispatch<Person>)Bus<Person>.Raise },
            { typeof(Bus<Thing>), (BusDispatch<Thing>)Bus<Thing>.Raise }
        };

    public static void Raise<T>(T eventData) where T : IDomainEvent
    {
        var busType = typeof(Bus<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T));
        busDispatch[busType].DynamicInvoke(eventData);
    }
}

public class SomeBase
{
    public override string ToString() { return Data != null ? Data.ToString() : string.Empty; }
    public object Data { get; set; }
}

public class Person : SomeBase, IDomainEvent { }

public class Phase1PersonHandler : IHandler<Person>
{
    public Person Handle(Person person)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Phase #1 {0}...", person);
        return person;
    }
}

public class Phase2PersonHandler : IHandler<Person>
{
    public Person Handle(Person person)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Phase #2 {0}...", person);
        return person;
    }
}

public class Thing : SomeBase, IDomainEvent { }

public class ThingHandler : IHandler<Thing>
{
    public Thing Handle(Thing thing)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Handling {0}...", thing);
        return thing;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Bus<Person>.Register(new Phase1PersonHandler());
        Bus<Person>.Register(new Phase2PersonHandler());
        Bus<Thing>.Register(new ThingHandler());

        AnyBus.Raise(new Person { Data = "Person 1" });
        AnyBus.Raise(new Thing { Data = "Thing 1" });
        AnyBus.Raise(new Person { Data = "Person 2" });

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

(where the only down casting that occurs is confined in that AnyBus.busDispatch private static field above and in the AnyBus.Raise implementation)

Testable here:

https://repl.it/Cte0/1

Another potential issue to be aware of with this sort of solution, though, is this reliance on Delegate.DynamicInvoke, as it is notoriously slow, compared to statically type checked delegate invocations -- so this may be an actual issue if you have really *a lot* of calls into that AnyBus.Raise vs the rest of your application.

[EDIT]
Another caveat of the above is it's obviously not thread-safe, so I just gave a shot at that here below:

https://repl.it/Cte0/12

(Cf. relevant code comments)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

/// <summary>
/// SE 328643:
/// List of any object T
/// http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/328643/list-of-any-object-t
/// </summary>
public interface IDomainEvent { }

public interface IHandler<T> where T : IDomainEvent
{
    // Btw, why this T return type (instead of void) if we ignore it in Bus<T>.Raise(...) anyway?
    T Handle(T eventData);
}

public class Bus<T> where T : IDomainEvent
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentBag<IHandler<T>> handlers = new ConcurrentBag<IHandler<T>>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Register a IHandler<T> handler for a Bus<T>
    /// (assuming the latter has a BusDispatch<T>, itself, already registered)
    /// </summary>
    public static void RegisterHandler<H>(H handler) where H : IHandler<T>
    {
        handlers.Add(handler);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoke all the registered IHandler<T>'s (if any) for the given event data, typed T
    /// </summary>
    public static void Raise(T eventData)
    {
        // Make sure the current thread is going to enumerate a frozen collection:
        var handlers = Bus<T>.handlers.Reverse().ToArray();
        // Now, enumerate:
        foreach (var handler in handlers)
        {
            handler.Handle(eventData);
        }
    }
}

public delegate void BusDispatch<T>(T eventData) where T : IDomainEvent;

public class AnyBus
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Delegate> busDispatch =
        new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Delegate>
        (
            new[]
            {
                // Let AnyBus know about a few hard-wired (aka "builtin") (BusDispatch<?>) Raise delegates
                new KeyValuePair<Type, Delegate>(typeof(Bus<Person>), (BusDispatch<Person>)Bus<Person>.Raise),
                new KeyValuePair<Type, Delegate>(typeof(Bus<Thing>), (BusDispatch<Thing>)Bus<Thing>.Raise)
            }
        );

    private static Type GetBusType<T>() where T : IDomainEvent
    {
        return typeof(Bus<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T));
    }

    private static void UnsupportedEventDataError(Unsupported unsupported)
    {
        var eventData = unsupported.WrappedEventData;
        throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Unsupported event data: {0}", (eventData != null ? eventData.GetType() : typeof(void)).Name));
    }

    internal class Unsupported : IDomainEvent
    {
        internal object WrappedEventData { get; set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Register a (BusDispatch<T>) Raise delegate for a given event data type T,
    /// or keep whichever existing one
    /// </summary>
    public static void RegisterDispatch<T>() where T : IDomainEvent
    {
        Func<Type, Delegate, Delegate> keepExisting = (type, @delegate) => @delegate;
        var busType = GetBusType<T>();
        busDispatch.AddOrUpdate(GetBusType<T>(), (BusDispatch<T>)Bus<T>.Raise, keepExisting);
    }

    public static void Raise<T>(T eventData) where T : IDomainEvent
    {
        var busType = GetBusType<T>();
        // We choose to use TryAdd(... UnsupportedEventData) as we want to be liberal enough
        // if it just so happens that another thread has just registered the (BusDispatch<T>) Raise we're precisely
        // interested in (for the provided event data, typed T);
        // however, we probably still *do* want to inform the application if it forgot to use,
        // AnyBus.RegisterDispatch<T>() -- throughout *all* threads -- prior to calling AnyBus.Raise
        busDispatch.TryAdd(busType, (BusDispatch<Unsupported>)UnsupportedEventDataError);
        if (!(busDispatch[busType] is BusDispatch<Unsupported>))
        {
            busDispatch[busType].DynamicInvoke(eventData);
        }
        else
        {
            UnsupportedEventDataError(new Unsupported { WrappedEventData = eventData });
        }
    }
}

public class SomeBase
{
    public override string ToString() { return Data != null ? Data.ToString() : string.Empty; }
    public object Data { get; set; }
}

public class Person : SomeBase, IDomainEvent { }

public class Phase1PersonHandler : IHandler<Person>
{
    public Person Handle(Person person)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Phase #1 {0}...", person);
        return person;
    }
}

public class Phase2PersonHandler : IHandler<Person>
{
    public Person Handle(Person person)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Phase #2 {0}...", person);
        return person;
    }
}

public class Thing : SomeBase, IDomainEvent { }

public class ThingHandler : IHandler<Thing>
{
    public Thing Handle(Thing thing)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Handling {0}...", thing);
        return thing;
    }
}

public class SomethingElse : SomeBase, IDomainEvent { }

public class SomethingElseHandler : IHandler<SomethingElse>
{
    public SomethingElse Handle(SomethingElse somethingElse)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Also handling {0}...", somethingElse);
        return somethingElse;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // AnyBus already knows about how to dispatch the Person and Thing domain event
        // (no need to call AnyBus.Register<?>() for those privileged ones)
        Bus<Person>.RegisterHandler(new Phase1PersonHandler());
        Bus<Person>.RegisterHandler(new Phase2PersonHandler());
        Bus<Thing>.RegisterHandler(new ThingHandler());

        // Now, pretend we forgot to write the following two lines -- especially the first one:
        //AnyBus.RegisterDispatch<SomethingElse>();
        //Bus<SomethingElse>.RegisterHandler(new SomethingElseHandler());

        try
        {
            AnyBus.Raise(new Person { Data = "Person 1" });
            AnyBus.Raise(new Thing { Data = "Thing 1" });
            AnyBus.Raise(new Person { Data = "Person 2" });
            AnyBus.Raise(new SomethingElse { Data = "Something else" });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ouch:\r\n{0}", ex.Message);
        }

        //Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

'HTH,

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the question is poorly asked. In its current form, I would have voted for closing because the main objective or obstacle of the question isn't well explained.

The fear of casting in C# is completely misplaced. Any attempt to workaround it will simply result in more complicated code that will also be slower. Judicious use of type-erasure (by casting to `object`, and then back), together with correctly implemented guard logic that makes an invalid cast impossible to happen, will make remove the many obstacles which are discussed in this question.

Use of type-erasure is worth considering, because `IHandler<IDomainEvent>` and `IHandler<Person>` are considered **not** belonging to the same inheritance hierarchy - they are unrelated, as far as inheritance is considered. The issue also affects delegates, such as `Action<object>` and `Action<People>`.

Thus, the first level dictionary is a mapping from `Type` to a sub-dictionary that handles specific types of data. The second level dictionary, meanwhile, will have to treat its values (`Action<?>` which are known to accept the data type associated with this level) as opaque.

Before discussing the proof-of-concept, I will point out some results from my benchmarking, to explain why the fears are misplaced.

The slowest part of the code, it turns out, is the `foreach (var handler in dict)`. This is slow even if the dictionary has zero, one, or more items.

The second slowest part is `Directory` indexer (item lookup). This is understandable because its implementation is non-trivial, and the performance cost is the price we pay for being able to store multiple items into a central place.

Finally, slowness comes from missing method inlining opportunity. This is again understandable because it is a price we pay for writing flexible reusable code.

The following is a proof-of-concept. This code evolves from the code in [YSharp's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/329445/620), so you should fully understand the earlier answer before trying to understand my code.

There are several parts worth pointing out. Firstly, concurrency is easy if you are not changing configuration concurrently - adding or removing handlers when other code are running. It is hard if you want to do this dynamically and concurrently. Even if this code is hardened, you will see race conditions in other parts of your own code, unless you write your code from first principles based on a definition of object lifetimes.

This code provides a method where, if a particular event type `T` is expected to occur repeatedly, the user can ask for a delegate (in the form of `Action<T>`) which can be stored and invoked repeatedly. Instead of traversing the two levels of dictionaries for each call, this delegate is synthesized by composition. This avoids the issue of `foreach`. In my benchmark testing, this performance tweak is more significant than any other performance concerns ever discussed in this question.

This code also provides another method where, given a event type `T`, it will not only search for handlers registered for `T` itself, but also for the base classes of `T`, as well as handlers registered for any interface `I` which is implemented by `T`. These handlers are also composed into a single delegate.

```
public class TypeErasedActionRegistry
{
    private static System.Reflection.BindingFlags flagInvokePublicStatic =
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod |
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static |
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public;

    private static ConcurrentDictionary<Type, ConcurrentBag<object>> actionForAll =
        new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, ConcurrentBag<object>>();

    public static void ThrowIfInvalidAction<T>(object typeErasedActionObject) where T : IDomainEvent
    {
        if (typeErasedActionObject == null ||
            !(typeErasedActionObject is Action<T>))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid action");
        }
    }

    public static void Register<T>(Action<T> action) where T : IDomainEvent
    {
        var actionBag = actionForAll.GetOrAdd(typeof(T),
            (Type _) => new ConcurrentBag<object>());
        actionBag.Add(action);
    }

    public static void Call<T>(T data) where T : IDomainEvent
    {
        ConcurrentBag<object> actionBag;
        actionForAll.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out actionBag);
        if (actionBag != null)
        {
            foreach (var typeErasedAction in actionBag)
            {
                ThrowIfInvalidAction<T>(typeErasedAction);
                Action<T> action = (Action<T>)typeErasedAction;
                action(data);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// <para>
    /// Given compile-time type T, retrieve and combine all handlers 
    /// that are registered to handle the type T.
    /// </para>
    /// <para>
    /// This method does not search handlers which are registered under  
    /// any types or interfaces other than T itself. In other words, 
    /// this method does not consider whether T might be assignable to 
    /// these types or interfaces.
    /// </para>
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// To search for handlers registered to handle related types 
    /// such as base types of T or interfaces implemented by T, use 
    /// <code>ComposeActionAndBaseTypes()</code>.
    /// </remarks>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Action<T> ComposeAction<T>() where T : IDomainEvent
    {
        Action<T> combinedAction = null;
        ConcurrentBag<object> actionBag;
        actionForAll.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out actionBag);
        if (actionBag != null)
        {
            foreach (var typeErasedAction in actionBag)
            {
                ThrowIfInvalidAction<T>(typeErasedAction);
                Action<T> action = (Action<T>)typeErasedAction;
                combinedAction = (combinedAction == null) ? (action) : (combinedAction + action);
            }
        }
        return combinedAction;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Given compile-time type T, search for handlers that accept either T,
    /// or one of its base types, or one of the interfaces implemented by T.
    /// Combine all qualifying handlers into a new Action delegate.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// <para>
    /// If no qualifying handlers exist, null is returned.
    /// </para>
    /// <para>
    /// If multiple qualifying handlers are found, they are combined in 
    /// unspecified, potentially non-deterministic order. User shall not 
    /// rely on any assumptions about specific ordering.
    /// </para>
    /// </remarks>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Action<T> ComposeActionAndBaseTypes<T>() where T : IDomainEvent
    {
        Type currentType = typeof(T);
        Action<T> combinedAction = null;
        while (typeof(IDomainEvent).IsAssignableFrom(currentType))
        {
            var method = typeof(TypeErasedActionRegistry).GetMethod("ComposeAction", flagInvokePublicStatic);
            var methodReified = method.MakeGenericMethod(currentType);
            var composeActionResult = methodReified.Invoke(null, null);
            if (composeActionResult != null)
            {
                Action<T> delegateForCurrentType = (Action<T>)composeActionResult;
                combinedAction = (combinedAction == null) ? (delegateForCurrentType) : (combinedAction + delegateForCurrentType);
            }
            currentType = currentType.BaseType;
        }
        return combinedAction;
    }
}
```